# Django 3.2 base template fails with error: Invalid block tag on line 11: 'raw'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, templates

I searched the internet and they said to use {%block raw}.
This fails with the error: only one raw block allowed.

I also tried substituting {% verbatim %}.  This also failed.

Why does Django 3.2 fail with:
Invalid block tag on line 11: 'raw'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

The template is:

```
{{"{% extends 'webapp/base.html' "}}{{ "%" }}} {{"{% block content "}}{{ "%" }}}
{{"{% if products "}}{{ "%" }}}
<div class="row mx-2">
  {{"{% for product in products "}}{{ "%" }}}
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 px-2 mb-3">
    <div class="card">
      <img
        src="{{product.image}}"
        class="img-fluid"
        style="padding: 30px"
        alt="{% raw %}{{product.title}}{% endraw %}"
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{% raw %}{{product.title}}{% endraw %}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          A beautiful {% raw %}{{product.title}} for ${{product.price}}{% endraw
          %}.
        </p>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{"{% endfor "}}{{ "%" }}}
</div>
{{"{% else "}}{{ "%" }}}
<p>No products available.</p>
{{"{% endif "}}{{ "%" }}} {{ "{% endblock " }}{{ "%" }}}
```

Comment: Probably you are referring to block incorrectly. Can you please try `{% block raw %}` ....`{% endblock %}`

Comment: What is the `{% raw %}` supposed to mean (There is no such builtin template tag)? Also what exactly are you doing with those weird `{{"{% ..."}}`??

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I should have provided a source.  https://auth0.com/blog/django-tutorial-building-and-securing-web-applications/    I am learning about Django and found on the Auth0 website this tutorial. I assumed the author knew what he was doing and so I thought the question was just the difference between Django versions and the author no longer works for the company.  I will just mark the question closed and learn more. I have no idea what those weird {{"{%...}}?? sequences are for.  I assumed the code worked since it was on Auth0's website.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below for your `raw` block without separating the `{%` and `%}` from the block syntax as follows:

```
{% block raw %} 

....

{% endblock %}
```

Further, please make sure to change the variable name {% raw %} in the following or alternatively, you may use it only once as there is no reason to duplicate the same block and give it the same value `{{product.title}}`

> ```
> alt="{% raw %}{{product.title}}{% endraw %}"
>
> <h5 class="card-title">{% raw %}{{product.title}}{% endraw %}</h5>
>
> <p class="card-text">
>           A beautiful {% raw %}{{product.title}} for ${{product.price}}{% endraw
>           %}.
>         </p>
> ```

You may use the block tag as follows:

```
{% block raw %}
<div class="card">
      <img
        src="{{product.image}}"
        class="img-fluid"
        style="padding: 30px"
        alt="{{product.title}}"
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          A beautiful {{product.title}} for ${{product.price}}.
        </p>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
      </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  When I change the raw to: { % block raw %}  {% endblock %}   I get the error 'block' tag with name 'raw' appears more than once.

Comment: Hi @ECheadle I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I should have provided a source. auth0.com/blog/… I am learning about Django and found on the Auth0 website this tutorial. I assumed the author knew what he was doing and so I thought the question was just the difference between Django versions and the author no longer works for the company. I will just mark the question closed and learn more. I have no idea what those weird {{"{%...}}?? sequences are for. I assumed the code worked since it was on Auth0's website